# Sort a collection with a property type Date value

Tags: sorting, collections

I have a collection as:

```
    content [Collection]    
        [0] [Content]   
            creationDate    Thu Aug 22 11:50:37 GMT 2019    
        [1] [Content]   
            creationDate    Thu Aug 22 11:45:37 GMT 2019    
        [2] [Content]   
            creationDate    Thu Aug 22 11:54:37 GMT 2019
```

How can I sort this collection by date value?

i.e.

```
    content [Collection]    
        [0] [Content]   
            creationDate    Thu Aug 22 11:45:37 GMT 2019    
        [1] [Content]   
            creationDate    Thu Aug 22 11:50:37 GMT 2019    
        [2] [Content]   
            creationDate    Thu Aug 22 11:54:37 GMT 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a DateComparator for sorting.

```
class DateComparator implements Comparator<Date> {
            public int compare(Date d1, Date d2) {
                if (d1.before(d2)) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (d1.after(d2)) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }        
            }
        }
```

and call content.sort(new DateComparator())

Comment: This comparator is obsolete, as `Date` does already implement `Comparable`. So `content.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());` or just `content.sort(null);` will do the job.